# How to update a global linked list in C?

Tags: c

I have a structure named ACCOUNT has two attributes and one pointer to the next.  the global head is initiated by NULL.  I want to update the global list but as I called the function several times, the head is still NULL.  How to fix it?

```c
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

     struct ACCOUNT{
                   int accountNumber;
                   float balance;
                    struct ACCOUNT *next;
} 
      struct ACCOUNT *head = NULL ;


     void findUpdate(int account, float amount){

        struct ACCOUNT *current;
        current = head;
        while(current!=NULL){
                if (current->accountNumber==account){
                        current->balance += amount;
                }
        current=current->next;
        }
         current = (struct ACCOUNT*) malloc(sizeof(struct ACCOUNT));
        current->accountNumber = account;
        current->balance = amount;
}
```

Comment: please fix the given code example so it is readable

Comment: You need to return in the while loop and update `head` after allocating `current`. Don't cast the pointer returned by malloc in c.

Comment: @LegendofPedro I'm sorry I don't follow,  could you please explain more details?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the new entry allocated at the end of `findUpdate` into the list. I suggest rewriting `findUpdate` as:

```
void findUpdate(int account, float amount)
  {
  struct ACCOUNT *current;

  for(current = head ; current != NULL ; current = current->next)
    {
    if(current->accountNumber == account)
      {
      current->balance += amount;
      break;
      }
    }

  if(current == NULL)
    {
    current = malloc(sizeof(struct ACCOUNT));
    current->accountNumber = account;
    current->balance = amount;
    current->next = head;
    head = current;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much!  I just tried it, but in this case,   multiple nodes with same accountNumber occurs in the list,   I only want one exists with the updated balance, how to deal with it?

Comment: This is building the list by adding new elements to the beginning of the list. `head` is NULL when the first element is allocated, so `current->next = head;` sets the `next` pointer of the first element of the list to NULL, and `head = current;` sets `head` to point to the first element allocated. When the next element is allocated `current->next=head;` sets the `next` pointer of the new element to point to the first element (pointed to by `head`), and `head=current;` sets `head` to point to the new (second) element. And so on for each element added.